# Django custom User model results in AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'authentication.User'

Tags: django

In my django app, called `authentication`, I created a custom user model, mostly following the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example).

In a previous project of mine it used to work, but now when I say:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

I'm constantly facing an error:

```
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'authentication.User'.
```

I've tested it with both python2 and python3, django versions 1.9 and 1.10

What might be wrong?

---

My code:

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, \
    BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

import uuid
import base64


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, name, password=None):
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            name=name,
            last_login=timezone.now()
        )  # last_login is defined in AbstractBaseUser
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=None,
            name=username,
            password=password
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


def generate_registration_code():
    return "asd"


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # This model should be created in the firest migration:
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

    # We use username, not email as primary user id, because OAuth
    # implementation via python-social-auth requires this field to
    # be present.
    username = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('username'),
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )

    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)

    # name is a human-readable name used to refer to user e.g. "Martin Taylor"
    # longest full name registered in guinness book is 744 letters-long
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('name'),
        max_length=1023,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    # We don't need password and last_login fields, because they are
    # already defined in AbstractBaseUser.

    # is_active is a variable in AbstractBaseUser set to True, but we
    # want a separate field for it.
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_('Is this user account activated?')
    )

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Is this user allowed to the admin page')
    )

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    code = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=generate_registration_code,
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_('''
            Code to be sent via e-mail upon registration
            or password recovery.
        ''')
    )

    new_password = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default="",
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_('''
            If user is attempting to change password, this field stores new
            password until user enters confirmation code.
        ''')
    )

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username
```

`settings.py`:

```
"""
Django settings for simple_resserver_jwt project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import datetime

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'co0)lyiwbgi4wz#80gp&y++bga-+iqd8hxq5boiw3d$g(#!yl*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'authentication',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'simple_resserver_jwt.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'simple_resserver_jwt.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['authentication.backends.AuthBackend', ]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',

   )
}

from  rest_framework_jwt.authentication  import JSONWebTokenAuthentication


with open('private') as f:
    PRIVATE_KEY =  f.readlines()

with open('public') as f:
    PUBLIC_KEY =  f.readlines()

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'authentication.utils.jwt_encode_handler',
    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'authentication.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    # 'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    # 'authentication.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': PRIVATE_KEY,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'RS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=300),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

UPDATE: 
Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 474, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 434, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 471, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework_jwt/views.py", line 56, in post
    if serializer.is_valid():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 411, in run_validation
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework_jwt/serializers.py", line 50, in validate
    user = authenticate(**credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 74, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
  File "/home/smith/Projects/simple_resserver_jwt/authentication/backends.py", line 13, in authenticate
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 198, in __get__
    cls._meta.swapped,
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'authentication.User'
```

Comment: Can you show the traceback? Somewhere you're using the default `User` model instead of your custom model.

Comment: @knbk You were right, I found a copy-pasted line `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` in my `backends.py`, where I called `user = User.objects.get(username=username)`. Thanks!